# If $\phi : \mathbb{Z}_6 \to \mathbb{Z}_3$ is a homomorphism, what is $\phi(3)$?

Tags: group-theory

If $\phi : \mathbb{Z}_6 \to \mathbb{Z}_3$ is a homomorphism, then the appropriate value of $\phi(3)$ is ... ?

I still beginner at abstract algebra, but I realize that my teacher's question seems uncomplete. On the book of mine, I found that the problem of this homomorphism always gives definition of ($\phi$) like $\phi(x) = x^2$. Could you give me an answer please.

Review :
It means, $$\begin{align*}\phi(3) &= \phi(1 + 1 + 1)\\ &= \phi(1) + \phi(1) + \phi(1)\\
                                     &= 3 \times \phi(1)\end{align*}$$

Because, $3 \times \phi(3) \pmod 3$ is $0$, so the answer is $0$, isn't it ?
But, I still confuse about some comment $\phi(1) = 1$, why ? I believe $\phi(1) = 2$ doesn't make any sense for getting the answer $0$ too, I believe $\phi(1)$ is something, but the key is the $\phi(1)$ multiplied by 3.

Comment: Yes it is true that some homomorphisms have explicit descriptions like that but not all of them do. Think about functions in general...you are happy to write f(x) as an arbitrary function without saying $f(x) = x^2$.

Comment: A quick $\LaTeX$ point: use `\times` as opposed to `x` for multiplication, as `\times` renders as $\times$ while `x` renders as $x$. And put everything inside the dollar brackets, as opposed to doing `3 x $\phi(1)$` and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\varphi(3)=\varphi(1+1+1)=\cdots$?

Comment: I still don't get it, please.

Comment: @Yagami Use that $\varphi$ is a (I take it group) homomorphism to get $\varphi(3)=3\cdot \varphi(1)$. This means...?

Comment: if phi(1) = 1, maybe phi(3) = 3 . phi(1) = 3, but why phi(1) = 1?
Please, my teacher didn't teach so well, so I must studying by myself, this problem itself I didn't find it on my guide book or another book that I learn.

Comment: The value of $\varphi(1)$ is irrelevant. All you need is that $\varphi(3)$ is divisible by $3$. =)

Comment: So the answer is 3 x phi(1) ?

Comment: @Yagami In $\Bbb Z_3$, $3=0$. So...?

Comment: I get it, so phi(3) = 0

Comment: @Yagami Correct.

Comment: Yes, see below.

Answer (score 2):

3 = 1+1+1 and use homomorphism.

After that, remember 3 = 0 in $\Bbb{Z}_3$

Update: 
 $\varphi(3)=\varphi(1+1+1)=\varphi(1)+\varphi(1)+\varphi(1)= 1+1+1=3$

3 = 0 in $\Bbb{Z}_3$

So the answer is 0

Comment: Actually, $3=0$ in $\mathbb Z_3$.

Comment: Right. Corrected it.

Comment: @Bernd, I understand the process, but the matter is why phi(1) = 1 ? 
Nb : How to write phi in 'phi' symbol in this site ?

Comment: Again, if the exercise is about group homomorphisms, $\varphi(1)$ doesn't have to be 1. Whatever $\varphi(1)$ is, $\varphi(3)$ is equal to $3 \cdot \varphi(1)$ which is equal to $0$ in $Z_3$.

Comment: It said in the excercise, that \varphi is a homomorphism. Then \varphi(1) = 1 (if we are talking about a ring homomorphism. If we are talking about a group homomorphism, \varphi(1) can be anything. Actually it is indeed not relevant, as long as we have 3 *\varphi(1) = 0 because 3 = 0 in \Bbb{Z}_3

Comment: As to the syntax: see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference 

However, I obviously don't know how to do it in the comments either :-(

Comment: Yes, I get it know @Bernd the point is the '$0$' value. In addition, I believe we're talking about group homomorphisms.

Answer (score 1):

Group $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ has order $3$ and consequently *every* element
$c\in\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ satisfies:

$c+c+c=0$

where $0$ denotes the
identity.

If $\phi:A\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ is a grouphomomorphism
and $a\in A$ can be written as $a=b+b+b$ then:

$\phi\left(a\right)=\phi\left(b+b+b\right)=\phi\left(b\right)+\phi\left(b\right)+\phi\left(b\right)=0$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: Thank you, repaired.

Answer (score 1):

To think about this question a different way, the [first isomorphism theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem) states that normal subgroups and homomorphisms are dual to one another. This implies that every homomorphism has a normal subgroup which is mapped to the identity, called the *kernel* of the map. If the map is $G\rightarrow H$ and kernel is $N$ then we have the following formula.
$$|G|/|N|=|H|$$

So, consider $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}_6\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_3$. By the above formula, $|N|$ divides two. Proving that every such subgroup contains the element $3$ then proves the result.

Answer (score 0):

First, $$\varphi(3)=3\varphi(1)$$
A homomorphism maps an identity to an identity. Therefore, $\varphi(1)=1$. It follows that
$$\varphi(3)=3\varphi(1)=3\equiv 0~~ (\mod(3))$$

Comment: The identity is 0!

Comment: I'm sorry for my stupidity, if I'm wrong.
I think the identity of this Z6 and Z3 is 0. Therefore, phi(0) = 0?

Comment: I believe Kaui is thinking in terms of ring homomorphisms, but OP is only indicating it is a group homomorphism, so $\phi(1)$ could be anything in $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @anon Any *non-identity* element. But only because three is prime.

Comment: @user1729 $\phi(1)$ could even be the identity, $0$. The reason $\phi(1)$ could be anything is not because three is prime, but because three divides six.

Comment: @anon I had a surjectivity assumption going around in my head which I forgot to mention...

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to see this, but actually you can ask yourself what the homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_6$ to $\mathbb Z_3$ are. There are only finitely many function from $\mathbb Z_6$ to $\mathbb Z_3$ anyway (namely $6^3$), but there are considerably fewer homomorphisms. How many? Which are they? Write them all down and see to which element they send $3$. Afterwards you can think about reasons for this and if you could have known that without looking at all examples.